# Nginx different root for only mainpage

Tags: laravel, nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to configure nginx to set two roots for one domain. My folder structure looks like:

```
/var/www/
         mainpage/
                  project/index.php
         backend/
                  public/index.php
```

I need to have root url `example.com` uses project in folder `mainpage` and all other urls uses project in folder `backend` (this is laravel app).
I have started to try to access `mainpage` project by url `example.com/mainpage`, but I'm receiving 403 or "Input file not specified". My nginx config:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root "/var/www/backend/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location /mainpage/ { 
        alias /var/www/mainpage/project;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    access_log off;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
```

This config return "403 forbidden". How should I configure nginx to work properly? And how to configure it to access mainpage for "/" url and other urls to use backend project

Answer (score 0):

You can set up root directory inside each location e.g.:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    root /your/root/directory;
}
```